# Declare public variables in Handlebar JS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, global-variables

I Would like to declare a global variable in my JS file and i would like to use that variable in different function in the same class .
I have declared a variable  in initialize section

```
       initialize: function () {              
                    this.regionid="";
    } 

          selectItems: function ()
                {

                this.regionid="10";
                this.Regions.url = this.Regions.url() + '?requesttype=1';
                this.Regions.fetch({ success: this.renderRegion });


    }

   renderRegion: function () {
            var ddlRegionClass = this.Regions.toJSON();
            $(this.el).find('[id=cboRegion] option').remove();          
            $.each(ddlRegionClass.LOCATIONS_Regions, function (j, cc1) {
                var data = 'data='+cc1.AreaCode_2;
                  var selected = '';                   
                    if(cc1.AreaCode_3==this.regionid)
                            selected="selected";                

                $('[id=cboRegion]').append('<option value="' + cc1.AreaCode_3 + '" ' + data + selected + '  >' + cc1.Area_Name + '</option>');
            })
        },
```

While i am checking  the value  at

```
 if(cc1.AreaCode_3==this.regionid)
```

i didnt get the value , it is showing 'undefined'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.regionid="";
initialize: function () {  
//some code
}
```

I think you have to declare like this..then it will work..you can assign values for variable in any function.

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the callback of `$.each` won't be referring to the `view` (or the object which the js file is containing).

In the initialize you can bind `renderRegion` with `this`:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.regionid = "";
  _.bindAll(this, "renderRegion");
}
```

and inside `renderRegion`:

```
renderRegion: function() {
  // before doing $.each store 'this' reference
  var _this = this;

  // and inside the callback use if(cc1.AreaCode_3 == _this.regionid)
}
```

It should work.